# Jquery modify check box attribute using children node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

how to get to the `checkbox` using `JQuery` children node.
I am using data table in my MVC project however I wanted to be able to modify my check box when data table returns the nRow which is `"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) { some modify here }.`
but I have a problem finding my way to the `check box`, I have tried few solutions but nothing works yet.

```
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1">
        <input type="checkbox" value="aasd"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        something here
    </td>
    <td>
        somthing here
    </td>
</tr>
```

start from `<tr class="odd">`

1. I have something like this `alert(nRow.nodeName);`  ---this line give me (TR)
2. I also tried `alert(nRow.children.nodeName);`   -- this line give me nothing, but I think it should give me (TD)
3. I also tried `alert(nRow.children()[0].nodeName);` -- this line dont even work.

Is my syntax wrong or something ? 
Is there a better way to find my check box via jquery ?

thank you for your time/help .

Comment: Can you provide some more of your Javascript/Jquery code? What exactly did you want to do? How did you call your function?

Comment: If it is just the selector you are having trouble with, then try $('tr' '

Comment: got it working $(nRow).find('input').attr('checked', true);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery:

```
$(nRow).find('input');
```

or to be very specific:

```
$(nRow).find('td').eq(0).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
```

To learn more about JQuery selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: or to even more specific `$(nRow).find('td').first().find('input[type="checkbox"]');` or even more and more `$(nRow).find('td:first').find('input[type="checkbox"]');`. and very very specific))) `$(nRow).find('td:first').find('input:checkbox');`:)

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak There is no limit, same as there is no limit to how long a route you can take from point A to point B. It's infinite.